# Read txt file from JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, html

I am trying to create a function that reads the content of a text file and then displays it on a new window. Right now this is my code:

```
function readFile(file)
    {
        var file = new XMLHttpRequest();
        file.open("GET", file, false);
        file.onreadystatechange = function ()
        {
            if(file.readyState === 4)
            {
                if(file.status === 200 || file.status == 0)
                {
                    var Text = file.responseText;
                    myWindow.document.write (Text);
                }
            }
        }
        file.send(null);
    }
```

I call the function later, passing the file's route as the parameter:

```
readFile("test.txt");
```

The problem is that it is displayed like this:

[image]

I would like the text in the file to be displayed as in a normal file, without all that information at the top and with the correct spacing.

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like some encoding mismatch. Please make sure that the editor you use saves the file as UTF-8

Comment: @LucaKiebel I did that and now it is showing the message without all that data which is the first step but it is all displayed in the same line

Comment: Make sure that it's also the same linebreak

Comment: @LucaKiebel sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: Different operating systems use different linebreaks. If you look at the file on a different OS, you are going to see different lines#

Comment: @LucaKiebel Thanks :) All doubts solved.